# Connection refused - connect(2) rails

Tags: solr, connection, rake

I copied a source code from github, and then I install ruby,rails,mysql...,which are necessary!
this is the config/database.yml :
common: &common
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  # socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

## common settings for any development databases

devel_common: &dev
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: wjn_123

## common settings for all test databases

tst_common: &tst
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: wjn_123

## common settings for all integration databases

int_common: &remote
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: wjn_123
.......

then I execute "rake eol:db:recreate RAILS_ENV=development" and there is no exception.but when I execute "rake eol:db:populate" and it gives me this :

Rebuilding BHL ...
Error accessing http:// localhost :8983/solr/bhl/update
"Connection refused - connect(2)"
.....

rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@upgrade/gems/webmock-1.8.11/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:98:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@upgrade/gems/webmock-1.8.11/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:116:in`start_without_connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@upgrade/gems/webmock-1.8.11/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:131:in `start'

so how can I solve the problem .
and I did not install jdk/jre . is that the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it might have anything to do with the issue mentioned by Houen in http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot?view=comments ?